# jquery show ul when class is in span

Tags: jquery, html-lists, html

I'm working on a small jQuery element and I'm pretty much done with the help of Stackoverflow and google but there's a small problem that I can't seem to figure out. Tried to solve it with CSS but that didn't go anywwhere.

I have jsFiddle for the project: http://jsfiddle.net/PcWjA/2/

Everything works fine, the add/subtract buttons work and the active class runs through the spans. But what I'm still missing is that when you're on the number 7 and then press the + button so it goes to 8 I want it to display the ul item. And when you go down to 7 the ul item goes hidden again.

Like I said I tried a few CSS solutions, add class/remove class etc but that doesn't seem to work. So I was thinking, is it possible to make the hidden ul shown when the class "spanval_active" is in the span class "more".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look, if this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/PcWjA/3/

So to explain:
You already are getting at what element is currently active (stored at `hour` variable), so we need to check if currently active element is higher than 7 or lower-equal. If it is higher then we need to show the list, we do that by calling jQuery method `.show()` on the list, if it is lower we hide the list with `.hide()`

```
    if (hour > 7) {
        $('.more .hour_dropdown').show();
    } else {
        $('.more .hour_dropdown').hide();
    }
```

Comment: if (hour > 7) {
            $('.more ul').show();
        } else {
            $('.more ul').hide();
        }
    }

It was really that simple huh, geez. I looked over an hour to find a css solution to this. Man, mindblowing.

Comment: +1 but a short explanation of what you attempted would still be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `update_hour` function to the following:

```
function update_hour()
{
    if (hour == 7) {
        $(".hour_dropdown").fadeOut(200); // use hide() for no animations
    }
    else if (hour == 8) {
        $(".hour_dropdown").fadeIn(200); // use show() for no animations
    }
    $('.spanval').removeClass('spanval_active');

    $('.spanval').eq( hour - 1 ).addClass('spanval_active');

    $('#hourvalue').val( hour );
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PcWjA/4/)